# How do I repeat a Sub row by row in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been able to send emails from Excel through Gmail, with certain Excel cells defining the meta-data, body, and attachment of the email.

This sub obviously only runs on the selected cells.  What I'd like ideally is for this sub to run on the first row (row 2 in this case), and then run on the next rows, until it has reached the end.

The end goal is to be able to automate the sending of customized emails via Excel.

Here's what I have so far.

```
Sub CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2()
    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim Flds As Variant

    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "MYEMAIL"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "MYPASSWORD"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With

    If Sheets("Data").Range("G2").Value = "Statement" Then
    strbody = "Test" & Sheets("Data").Range("E2").Value
    Else
    strbody = "Test 2"
    End If

    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = Sheets("Data").Range("A2").Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .ReplyTo = Sheets("Data").Range("D2").Value
        .From = Sheets("Data").Range("C2").Value & "<EMAIL>" 'This just changes the name, the email will come from 'sendusername' above
        .Subject = Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Value
        .TextBody = strbody
        .AddAttachment "" 'don't put in "", just write direct path to file. Possible to do non-local?
        .Send
    End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks everyone.

Comment: Add parameters to `Sub CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2()` for recipient, then change `.To = Sheets("Data").Range("A2").Value` to that parameter, e.g. `.To = Recipient`. Do the same for the other changing parameters. Lastly, run `foreach` loop, e.g. `foreach i in Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A10")` and then `Call Sub CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2(Parameters)`.

Comment: @nhee - Take the time to write this up as an answer using two subs.

Comment: @Jeeped and Jules Hill, please see below.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two subs, the first one being the existing one so send an e-mail, the second one to call the first one for a set of e-mail addresses.

For the first one, **CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2**, make these changes to make it "parameterized" (as opposed to the hardcoded version that it is now):

```
' Add some parameters to the Sub declaration
Sub CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2(RecipientAddress As String, ReplyToAddress As String, _
    Subject As String, FromAddress As String, Statement As String, _
    ValueOfColumnE As String)

    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim Flds As Variant

    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "MYEMAIL"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "MYPASSWORD"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With

    If Statement = "Statement" Then
        strbody = "Test" & ValueOfColumnE 'Use sub parameter
    Else
        strbody = "Test 2"
    End If

    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = RecipientAddress 'Use sub parameter
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .ReplyTo = ReplyToAddress 'Use sub parameter
        .From = FromAddress 'Use sub parameter
        .Subject = Subject 'Use sub parameter
        .TextBody = strbody 
        .AddAttachment "" 
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

The second one, let's call it **Send_Messages**, should look like this:

```
Sub Send_Messages()
    Dim RecipientAddress As String, ReplyToAddress As String, _
    Subject As String, FromAddress As String, Statement As String, _
    ValueOfColumnE As String

    ' change to match length of recipient list
    For Each i in Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A100") 
        RecipientAddress = i.Value
        ReplyToAddress = i.Offset(0,3).Value
        Subject = i.Offset(0,1).Value
        FromAddress = i.Offset(0,2).Value
        Statement = i.Offset(0,6).Value
        ValueOfColumnE = i.Offset(0,4).Value

        Call CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2(RecipientAddress, ReplyToAddress, Subject, _
        FromAddress, Statement, ValueOfColumnE)

        ' Shorter alternative (the above variable declarations wouldn't be needed, then
        ' Call CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2(i.Value, i.Offset(0,3).Value, i.Offset(0,1).Value, _
        'i.Offset(0,2).Value, i.Offset(0,6).Value, i.Offset(0,4).Value)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Explanation:**

The first sub was changed from one with hardcoded recipient addresses etc. to a parameter-based sub. It can now be run by other subs passing these parameters.

The second sub does just that. It goes through every cell in A2 to A100 and calls the first sub with the data from that row. While doing that, `i` becomes this cell from column A, hence in the first run, `i` equals `Sheets("Data").Range("A2")`. Column A contains the recipients, column B the subject lines and so on. To pass the subject line (and remaining parameters) to the `CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2` sub, we use the `.Offset(rows, cols)` method. It is used to reference cells by their relative distance from another cell, i.e. `i` equals `A2`, so `i.Offset(0,1)` equals `B2` whereas `i.Offset(1,0)` would equal `A3`. To make it easier to understsand, I am declaring variables for the parameters and setting them with the `Offset` method. As you can see in the code, this step can be skipped and the `Offset` method be used in the `Call` command directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a For loop to achieve this:

```
nRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i=2 To nRows
   //your code here, but referring to i instead of row 2...
Next
```

Where you refer to rows like this for example:

```
 .To = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & i).Value
```

Comment: It's highlighting "xlUp" and saying "Compile error: Invalid outside procedure".  It's not highliting "End" as a funciton

Comment: Also, I forgot to include, i have a "Option Explicit" at the very top of the code I originally posted.

Comment: Does the code you wrote go inside the "Sub" statements?

Comment: Yes, the code I wrote goed inside the Sub statements as well. And your code goes inside the For...Next loop, replacing al the "2"'s bij "& i" outside the quote marks. With option explicit you should also declare DIm i As Integer and Dim nRows as Integer at the top of your script.